# Validate attachment content type Paperclip in Rails 2 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord, paperclip

In my Rails 2 application, images for products are uploaded using Paperclip as a plugin. I need to restrict the image types to jpeg and png and also allow saving of product even if image is not uploaded.

The current code is

```
has_attached_file :master_image,
  :url  => "/images/products/:id/private/master.img",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/images/products/:id/private/master.img"

validates_attachment_content_type :master_image, :content_type => ['image/png', 'image/jpg'] , :message => "image must be jpg or png." , :allow_nil => true
```

I added `:allow_nil => true`  but it is not working.

I am getting `image must be jpg or png` when trying to save without image.

Is it possible to do the validation only if an attachment is included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `image must be jpg or png` when trying to save without image because if the image is not present which implies that the content type is also missing i.e. they are not `jpg` or `png`.

To accomplish your task, you can add a custom validator where first you will check if the image is present and if yes, only then you will check the `:content_type` of the image.

Add these in your `Product` Model:

```
  validate :master_image_type_present

  def master_image_type_present
    if master_image.present? && !(['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'image/jpeg'].include? master_image_content_type)
      errors.add(:content_type, "invalid content type")
    end
  end
```

And, your validation will work as expected.

Comment: It is still not passing when there is no image. I tried in every way I found.

Comment: When using image.present? it always returns a paperclip object. I tries with image.exists? but it returns true when there is already an image saved.

Comment: What I want to check is whether there is an image added as attachment when trying to save. It should not return true if there is an image previously saved.

Comment: validates_attachment_content_type :master_image, :content_type => [‘image/jpeg’, ‘image/jpg’, ‘image/png’] unless :master_image

Comment: I tried the above piece of code. It allows saving but is also allowing any type of image to get uploaded.

Comment: @Aswathy sorry, it should have been `master_image.present?` NOT `image.present? `. I have updated my answer. Could you try it and let me know if that works now?

Comment: Also, can you please show me your `Product` model how it looks like?

Comment: http://collabedit.com/5kjws   This is my product.rb. And I used master_image only. Not image.

Comment: Right, I have updated the code a bit. There was a small problem in the logic. Could you please try my latest updated answer? and let me know? I think it will work as expected now.

Comment: I cannot see any changes made to the code. Can please you share it here??

Comment: look at the answer again. The code under the `Updated code` section

Comment: I have modified the validator logic and it should work now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87129/discussion-between-aswathy-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).

Comment: I had to add  `unless master_image_file_name.blank?` to the `master_image_type_present` code block. `master_image.present?` seem to return true.

Comment: I see! Hard to tell without seeing the full code :-)